# loopback foreignKey as string with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, loopback

I'm having some trouble with loopback.

I'm trying to set a HasMany relationship with a foreignKey as STRING.
But it does not seem to work properly.

### TABLE_A

- id
- code_a(string)
- label_a(string)

### TABLE_B

- id
- code_b(string)
- label_b(string)
- code_a(string)

So it look like this:

TABLE_A

```
{
  "name": "TABLE_A",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "label_a": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "code_a": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "tablebs": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "TABLE_B",
      "foreignKey": "code_a"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

TABLE B

```
{
  "name": "TABLE_B",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "label_b": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "code_b": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't seem to work? If it's a standard _many-to-one_ connection, you might want to define a [BelongsTo](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/BelongsTo-relations.html) relation in a TABLE_B model.